# How to redirect/transfer from .ashx file without opening new tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, ashx

Im making some changes to a website i haven't developed before. All links opened via a go.ashx page to verify that it was used by a logged in user.. When the .ashx verifies the user ut openes the URL via `context.Response.Redirect(url, true);` This openes a new tab, how do i make it just a redirect without the new tab?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` can't open new tab. The problem somewhere else (i.e. `target` attribute on links).

Comment: have you used anchor or links with target to new this too can be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem can be with the links

```
<a href="target URL" target="new">anchor text</a>
```

or even

```
<a href="target URL" target="_blank">anchor text</a>
```

It should be like

```
<a href="target URL" target="_self">anchor text</a>
```

the target should be self.
 If you can post your link then it can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! The problem had to do with the links.